# cannot find symbol, although import statement is included

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to find the subsequence of two arrays `A` and `B`. My code is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        PrintWriter wr = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        int T = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());
        for(int t_i = 0; t_i < T; t_i++)
        {
            String[] line = br.readLine().split(" ");
            int N = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
            int M = Integer.parseInt(line[1]);
            int X = Integer.parseInt(line[2]);
            String[] arr_A = br.readLine().split(" ");
            int[] A = new int[N];
            for(int i_A = 0; i_A < arr_A.length; i_A++)
            {
                A[i_A] = Integer.parseInt(arr_A[i_A]);
            }
            String[] arr_B = br.readLine().split(" ");
            int[] B = new int[M];
            for(int i_B = 0; i_B < arr_B.length; i_B++)
            {
                B[i_B] = Integer.parseInt(arr_B[i_B]);
            }

            String out_ = solve(N, M, X, A, B);
            System.out.println(out_);
            
         }

         wr.close();
         br.close();
    }
    static String solve(int N, int M, int X, int[] A, int[] B){
        
        int k=0;
        Arraylist<Arraylist<Integer>> arr=new Arraylist<>(); //subsequence of array A
        Arraylist<Arraylist<Integer>> arr_1=new Arraylist<>(); // subsequence of array B
        Arraylist<Integer> temp=new Arraylist<>();
        int count=0;

        arr.add(A);

        //subsequence of array A
        while(k!=arr.size()){
            if(arr.get(k).size!=1){
                for(int i=0;i<arr.get(k).size();i++){
                    for(int j=0;j<arr.get(k).size();j++){

                        if(i!=j){
                        temp.add(arr.get(k).get(j));
                        }

                    }
                    if(!arr.contains(temp))
                        arr.add(temp);
                    temp.clear();
                } 
                ++k; 
            }
            else
                break;
        }

        arr_1.add(B);
        k=0;

        //subsequence of array B
        while(k!=arr_1.size()){
            if(arr_1.get(k).size!=1){
                for(int i=0;i<arr_1.get(k).size();i++){
                    for(int j=0;j<arr_1.get(k).size();j++){

                        if(i!=j){
                        temp.add(arr_1.get(k).get(j));
                        }

                    }
                    if(!arr_1.contains(temp))
                        arr_1.add(temp);
                    temp.clear();
                } 
                ++k; 
            }
            else
                break;
        }


            
        for(int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++){
            if(arr.get(k).size()==arr_1.get(k).size()){
                for(int j=0; j<arr_1.size()-1; j++){

                    if((arr.get(i).get(j)<arr_1.get(i).get(j)) && arr_1.get(i).get(j)<arr.get(i).get(j+1))
                        ++count;
                }
                if (count==X){
                    temp.addAll(arr.get(i));
                    temp.addAll(arr_1.get(i));
                    break;
                }
                else
                    count=0;
            }
        }

        if(temp.size()==X)
            return "YES";
        else
            return "NO";
    }
}
```

Now, when I run the code, I am greeted with the error `Cannot find symbol Arraylist...`, all over the code. I have also included the `import` statement, but it didn't solve anything. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is that it is supposed to be `ArrayList` (with a big L), not `Arraylist`.

Let me know if it helped!